# How to find which variable is greater with cypress

Tags: sorting, automated-tests, e2e-testing, cypress

Pls help me. 
I have a 2 variables and want to know which variable is greater with cypress.
Like this:

```
if(rejectedCount > sortedCount){
    return true
} else return false
```

Are there any assertion for it.

This is my code

cy.get('.list-table-list-item').eq(0)

```
.find('.reject span')
.invoke('text')
.then(text => {
     const rejectedCount = text;
     cy.get('.sortingReject').click();
     cy.get('.list-table-list-item').eq(0)
         .find('.reject span')
         .invoke('text')
         .then(text => {
              const sortedCount = text;
             // There should be my assertion Like this
              cy.get(sortedCount).should('be.gt', rejectedCount);

           });
  });
```

But it not working right. 
Pls help me!

Comment: I found my answer. THis is right assertion...  
assert.isAbove(sortedCount, rejectedCount)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `expect`

```js
expect(sortedCount).to.be.gt(rejectedCount)
```

https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/introduction-to-cypress.html#Explicit-Subjects

Comment: I am using assert.isAbove(sortedCount, firstCount) But Your answer working right too, thanks